# Problem with the size of object in the blender interface after changing to a bigger monitor

Tags: interface

I recently changed my monitor with a bigger one. Windows normally controls the zoom of the apps, but I found some problems in blender. In edit mode for example the cross of the pointer is so small that I can't see it. I tried to increase the dpi from settings and the problem is partially resolved. Anyways, the arrow and other things are really small, so I can't work as well as I would in edit mode and so on. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In order to **enlarge** the **cursor size**, font size and the overall windows, you can always go to **User Preferences** by pressing **CTRL+ALT+U** or by navigating through **File drop-down** menu. You will find many options there. Two such options are depicted below.[image] **Scale** your blender Windows accordingly and check on **Large Cursors**. Navigate through other options and you will eventually get a good view of the cursor and Windows. Alternatively, you can also use Windows **Magnifier** to see Whats there on the screen from a fairly far distance. Don't forget to **Save** changes.

Comment: "Large Cursors" seems to be gone in recent versions.